# I want to call an intent on click listener in recycler view but same activity in opening whenever i am clicking on it

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

```
    Setter set = teacherlist.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(set.get_TName());
    holder.Age.setText("Age: "+set.get_age());
    holder.Contact.setText("Contact: "+set.get_Contact());
    holder.Address.setText("Qualification: "+set.getAddressd());
    holder.qualification.setText(("Subject: "+set.get_Qualification()));
    holder.Rate.setText("Rates: "+set.get_Rates());
    holder.time.setText("Time: "+set.get_Time());
    holder.Special.setText("Address: "+set.get_subject());

    holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),show_teachers.class);
          context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

In onBindViewHolder i want to call another activity but same activity is opening whenever i calling a listener
Note:Recycler is taking values from MYSQL through another cardview activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```html
Intent intent = new Intent(context,show_teachers.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Tip: You shouldn't start your class name with lower case letters